# Regex Issue when log format has multiple ip's

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-greedy, fluentd

I have an issue with fluenTd log parser. The following config works fine when there are 2 ip’s.

```
expression  /^(?<client_ip>[^ ]*)(?:, (?<lb_ip>[^ ]*))? (?<ident>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) (?<protocol>[A-Z]{1,}[^ ]*)+\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)/
```

This matches:

```
148.165.41.129, 10.25.1.120 - - [09/Dec/2019:16:22:23 +0000] "GET /comet_request/44109669162/F1551019433002Y5MYEP?F155101943300742PMLG=1551019433877&_=1575904426457 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0 0
```

When there are 3 ip’s, i get a pattern not match warning.

This doesn't match :

```
176.30.235.70, 165.225.70.200, 10.25.1.120 - - [09/Dec/2019:13:30:57 +0000] \"GET /comet_request/71142769981/F1551018730440IY5YNF?F1551018721447ZVKYZ4=1551018733078&_=1575898029473 HTTP/1.1\" 200 0 0 0
```

I tried the following regex, but doesn't work.Can someone please help?

```
expression /^(?<client_ip>[^ ]*)(?:, (?<proxy_ip>[^ ]*))? (?:, (?<lb_ip>[^ ]*))? (?<ident>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) (?<protocol>[A-Z]{1,}[^ ]*)+\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)$/
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the IPs with a more specific pattern, like `[\d.]+` or `[^, ]+`, and make sure you also match the last two fields (you are not matching them and `$` requires the end of line/string).

Use a pattern like

```
^(?<client_ip>[^ ,]+)(?:, +(?<proxy_ip>[^ ,]+))?(?:, +(?<lb_ip>[^ ,]+))? (?<ident>[^ ]+) (?<user>[^ ]+) \[(?<time>[^\]\[ ]* [^\]\[ ]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>\S+) (?<protocol>[A-Z][^" ]*)[^"]*)?" (?<code>\S+) (?<size>\S+) \S+ \S+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rlCOc6/1)

The IP matching part is `^(?<client_ip>[^ ,]+)(?:, +(?<proxy_ip>[^ ,]+))?(?:, +(?<lb_ip>[^ ,]+))?`, see that `[^ ,]+` matches 1+ chars other than a space and `,` and `\S+ \S+` are added at the end of the pattern (if these are numbers, you may use `\d+ \d+` and capture them if needed).

Answer (score 0):

**Example strings**

Let's consider an abbreviated version of your question, focusing on the first four named ranges (as dealing with the remaining named ranges is straightforward).

```
str1 = "148.165.41.129, 10.25.1.120 - - [09/Dec/2019:16:22:23 +0000]"
```

```
str2 = "176.30.235.70, 165.225.70.200, 10.25.1.120 - - [09/Dec/2019:13:30:57 +0000]"
```

**The regular expression written in free-spacing mode**

The following regular expression can be used to extract the contents of the named ranges, provided the string has a valid structure. Notice that it requires IPv4 addresses and the date-time string to have valid patterns (rather than merely `[^ ]+` and `[^ ]+ [^ ]+`). I've written the regular expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \A              # match the beginning of the string 
    (?<client_ip>   # begin a capture group named client_ip
      \g<user_ip>   # evaluate the subexpression (capture group) named user_ip
    )               # end capture group client_ip
    (?:             # begin a non-capture group
      ,[ ]          # match the string ', '
      (?<lb_ip>     # begin a capture group named lb_ip
        \g<user_ip> # evaluate the subexpression (capture group) named user_ip
      )             # end capture group lb_ip
    )?              # end non-capture group and optionally execute it
    (?:             # begin a non-capture group
      ,[ ]          # match the string ', '
      (?<user_ip>   # begin a capture group named user_ip
        \d{1,3}     # match 1-3 digits 
        (?:         # begin a non-capture group
          \.\d{1,3} # match a period followed by 1-3 digits
        ){3}        # end the non-capture group and execute 3 times
      )             # end capture group user_id
    )               # end non-capture group
    [ ]-[ ]-[ ]\[   # match the string ' - - ['
    (?<time>        # begin a capture group named time 
      \d{2}\/\p{L}{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[ ]\+\d{4}
                    # match a time string
    )               # end capture group time                    
    \]              # match string ']'
    \z              # match end of string
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

**Match the strings against the regular expression**

We now confirm the two strings match this regular expression and extract the contents of the capture groups.

```
    m1 = str1.match(r)
    m1.named_captures
      #=> {"client_ip"=>"148.165.41.129",
      #    "lb_ip"=>nil,
      #    "user_ip"=>"10.25.1.120",
      #    "time"=>"09/Dec/2019:16:22:23 +0000"}
```

```
    m2 = str2.match(r)
    m2.named_captures
      #=> {"client_ip"=>"176.30.235.70",
      #    "lb_ip"=>"165.225.70.200",
      #    "user_ip"=>"10.25.1.120",
      #    "time"=>"09/Dec/2019:13:30:57 +0000"}
```

**Subexpression Calls**

Rather than replicating the content of the capture group `user_ip` for each of the first two named capture groups I have simply used `\g<user_ip>`, which, in effect, tells the regex engine to evaluate the contents of capture group (subexpression) `user_ip` at the location where `\g<user_ip>` is referenced. Search for "Subexpression Calls" in the docs for [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html).

Notice that the subexpression calls are *forward-looking*. Suppose we instead wrote:

```
r = /
    \A 
    (?<client_ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
    (?:,[ ](?<lb_ip>\g<client_ip>))?
    (?:,[ ](?<user_ip>\g<client_ip>))
    [ ]-[ ]-[ ]\[
    (?<time>\d{2}\/\p{L}{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[ ]\+\d{4}) 
    \]
    \z
    /x
```

Then

```
    m1 = str1.match(r)
    m1.named_captures
      #=> {"client_ip"=>"10.25.1.120",
      #    "lb_ip"=>nil,
      #    "user_ip"=>"10.25.1.120", 
      #    "time"=>"09/Dec/2019:16:22:23 +0000"}
```

```
    m2 = str2.match(r)
    m2.named_captures
      #=> {"client_ip"=>"10.25.1.120",
      #    "lb_ip"=>"165.225.70.200",
      #    "user_ip"=>"10.25.1.120",
      #    "time"=>"09/Dec/2019:13:30:57 +0000"}
```

As seen, the contents of the capture group `client_ip` is set equal to the contents of `user_ip`. The reason for this behaviour is explained [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) (look for "In PCRE but not Perl, one interesting twist is..." and other referenced sections of that document).

**The regular expression written conventionally**

The regular expression is conventionally written as follows:

```
/\A(?<client_ip>\g<user_ip>)(?:, (?<lb_ip>\g<user_ip>))?(?:, (?<user_ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})) - - \[(?<time>\d{2}\/\p{L}{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4})\]\z/
```

Notice that where there are spaces in the above there are character classes containing a single space when the regex is written in free-spacing mode. That is necessary because in free-spacing mode unprotected spaces are removed before the expression is parsed. Another way to protect spaces is to escape them (`\`). If it is desired to use whitespaces rather than spaces, `\s` can be used.